# How do the opening skills work?

Tags: blood-brothers

How do the opening skills work? Do different familiars with the same opening skill have better effects?

Answer (score 1):

The skills depends on the attribute they are based off of, some use attack, some use magic, and some use agility. So once you determine what the skill uses you can have a thought on what it will do. So a familiar with the same skill and has a higher attribute that skill is based off of will do more damage to the opponent.